# На сколько это безопасно и есть ли похожие решения на JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть код на PHP который изменят содержания файла.

```
<?php
$file = "test.js";
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
$text = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
?>  
<form method="post">
<textarea name="text"><?=$text?></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Так вот я бы хотел узнать, как сделать что бы этот код не полностью изменял файл а добавлял новые строки в тот файл и на сколько это безопасно и есть ли похожие решения на JS?

Comment: js работает на стороне клиента - вы холите менять локальные файлы?

Comment: а что касается добавлял - добавьте третий параметр `FILE_APPEND Если файл filename уже существует, данные будут дописаны в конец файла вместо того, чтобы его перезаписать`

Comment: помогите пожалуйста с таким кодом, только нужно что бы дописовалось вверх

Comment: в начало файла? `file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text'] . file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: не совсем пойму как прикрутить это к момему коду